# Why is Excel's datevalue function returning #VALUE

Tags: excel, date, spreadsheet

I want to convert a column of text values looking like this:

[image]

(month is first) into a column of Excel date values.

For some reason the DATEVALUE function is not working.

For example, when I put the following formula, which is an example [from the documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252), into a cell:

```
=DATEVALUE("1/1/2008")
```

The cell displays:

[image]

The documentation says this should produce the value 39448.

A different example from the above documentation page does work:

```
=DATEVALUE("30-Jan-2008")
```

returns 39477.

I'm using Excel 16.45 for Mac OS X.

Comment: what is your local setting for short date?

Comment: How do I find that?  Is that a system setting or an Excel setting?

Comment: I just noticed that `DATEVALUE("1/1/08")` works (returns 36899). Is it just the documentation that is wrong?  Can someone confirm whether `DATEVALUE("1/1/2008")` works on their Excel?

Comment: Ah, but 36899 is `2001-01-08` so that's obviously not what I was looking for.

Comment: That means your system local settings for short date is y/m/d. And is why you get error with a different format. It works for.me because my setting is m/d/y. Try DATEVALUE("2008/1/1")

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner that is the answer.  I knew the day/month formats could be different but I didn't realize I had set a short date format with year first. Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone know where the 'short date' setting is located on Mac OS X?  How do you change it?  (I tried looking in Date & Time preferences and Language and Region preferences but couldn't find it).  Or is it fixed (e.g. determined by my region)?

Comment: I found the answer here: [Change how dates, times, and more display on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mh27073/mac)